# Свой класс исключений

Tags: c++, ооп, исключения

```
#include "state.h"
#include <iostream>
 
class Error : public std::runtime_error {
 
public:
 
    Error(const char *msg, State state);
 
    State GetState() const;
 
private:
 
    State state_;
};
```

```
#include "../include/error.h"
 
using namespace std;
 
Error::Error(const char *msg, State state) : std::runtime_error(msg), state_(state){
 
}
 
State Error::GetState() const {
 
    return state_;
}
```

Всем привет! Хочу написать свой класс исключений со своими кодами ошибок. Если посмотреть на встроенные исключения в C++, то как я понял есть базовый класс `std::exception` от которого наследуются другие классы исключений, например `runtime_error` и т.д. В своем классе, я также планирую делать наследование от `runtime_error`, потому-что у него есть конструктор принимающий char *.

Стоит ли мне также делать много классов исключений для разных ошибок, или же у меня появилась идея что в моем классе исключений будет поле `ENUM`, в котором будут коды ошибок, и тогда мне не придется делать много разных класссов. Получится, что ошибки группируются в одном месте (тип enum) и нет необходимости создавать иерархии исключений, чтобы различать разные типы ошибок. Или это бред?

Comment: на мой взгляд наследоваться стоит от базового класса исключений, все остальное придумки — конструктор и прочее Вы вполне можете реализовать сами с любыми параметрами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам класс написан правильно. Нужен только второй конструктор с параметром `const std::string &` вместо `const char *`, чтобы было по канону (в `runtime_error` сделано так же).

Если вы храните строку с ошибкой, то наследоваться напрямую от `std::exception` не стоит. Потому что `std::runtime_error` и прочие хранят ее не в лоб, а грамотно (в некотором подобии `shared_ptr`, чтобы копирование никогда не бросало исключения). Лучше наследоваться от `runtime_error`, и хранить строку в нем.

---

> Стоит ли мне также делать много классов исключений для разных ошибок

Имхо, кастомные классы исключений вообще не нужны в 99% случаев, потому что в 99% случаев исключения либо не ловят, либо ловят одним большим `try` в `main`, печатают, и роняют программу. Либо ловят, чтобы дописать что-то в строку и кинуть дальше.

Поэтому используйте `std::runtime_error` и все.

Когда вам потребуется ловить исключения в другом месте и как-то по-особому обрабатывать их разные типы, тогда уже выбирать между enum-ом или множеством классов.

Comment: Все эти советы и утверждения далеко неоднозначны.  Подходы не бывают одинаковыми во всех ситуациях. Но  исключения только для исключительных ситуаций,  а  кастомные тем более...